# Is it possible to combine a ZipOutputStream and a DigestOutputstream?

Tags: java, stream, zip, checksum

I need to determine the checksum of a `.zip` file before uploading it somewhere, so that file integrity may be assured.

Currently, I have something like the following:

```
        for (File file : zipCandidates) {
            InputStream fileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
            ZipUtils.addDataToZip(zipStream, fileInputStream, file.getName());
            boolean deleted = file.delete();
            if (!deleted) {
                log.error("Failed to delete temporary file {} : {}", file.getName(), file.getAbsolutePath());
            }
        }
        zipStream.close();

        // checksum and filesize
        long fileSize = zipFile.length();
        InputStream fileInputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(zipFile);
        BufferedInputStream bufferedFileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        String checksum = DigestUtils.md5Hex(bufferedFileInputStream);

        bufferedFileInputStream.close();


        // upload
        fileInputStream = FileUtils.openInputStream(zipFile);
        bufferedFileInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(fileInputStream);
        val writer = writerFactory.createWriter(blobName, fileSize, checksum);
        writer.write(bufferedFileInputStream);

        bufferedFileInputStream.close();
```

Needless to say, this is very inefficient as I have to read each `.zip` file *twice* to be able to discern its checksum before uploading it.

Is there some way that I can combine my `ZipOutputStream` above and a `DigestOutputstream`, so that I can just update my checksum while writing the zip file? Unfortunately, since the output stream has to be a `ZipOutputStream`, I cannot simply decorate it (i.e. `new DigestOutputStream(zipStream, digest)`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Unfortunately, since the output stream has to be a `ZipOutputStream`, I cannot simply decorate it (i.e. `new DigestOutputStream(zipStream, digest)`).

You wouldn't want to anyway, because you want to digest the *result* of the zipping operation, so you need to wrapper the `DigestOutputStream` with the `ZipOutputStream`, i.e. the other way:

```
try (ZipOutputStream zipStream = new ZipOutputStream(
                                   new DigestOutputStream(
                                     new FileOutputStream(zipFile),
                                     digest))) {
    // code adding zip entries here
}
String checksum = Hex.encodeHexString(digest.digest());
```

Notice the use of try-with-resources to ensure your `ZipOutputStream` is always closed correctly.

Comment: I see. I guess I had misconstrued how the `DigestOutputStream` functioned - I did not realize that the `digest` would be mutated by the stream and can be read at a later time. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can certainly construct an output stream of your own that wraps two output streams (in your specific case, one would be your ZipOutputStream and the other your DigestOutputStream). Your new output stream implementation would write each byte that it receives to both of the wrapped streams.

This use case is common enough that you probably will find an open source version that will meet your needs (e.g., [this one from apache commons](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.5/org/apache/commons/io/output/TeeOutputStream.html)).